# Using dash in the dynamic route name in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

As you know, in order to have dynamic route in Nuxt.js, we should use Underline (_) before the dynamic name. For example the name of the file should be:

```
_id.vue
```

The problem is that I want to write something like article-name instead of id. However, the name of folder which should be:

```
_article-name.vue
```

leads to error and breaks the projext. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt does not support dynamic route names with dashes.

The dynamic route name (i.e., `article-name` here) is passed to [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#parameters) (via Vue Router), which requires named parameters to consist of word characters (alphanumeric characters and the underscore).

A potential workaround is to use underscore instead of dash:

```
_article_name.vue
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-dyamic-route-names)